Ubuntu installation skips some steps
After I boot from USB flash drive, Ubuntu doesn't ask me about language, installation setup, login details or credentials. It just starts on its own skipping those steps, but it's slow and freezes.

You've provided few specifics so we're somewhat limited in being able to help you.  We have no clues as to what Ubuntu product, what release (there are different installers where the ISO you download controls which you use, and you've not specified) so we can't know what you expected & were using. You've also not said if you validated ISO or how it was written to media (as per docs? or something else? as this can influence installation too).

This question is similar to: Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
